# Common Lisp - apply function to every other element in list

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp

I want to apply the function (* x 2) to every other element in a list and return the entire list using the *loop* macro. The solution I've come up with so far is this:

```
(defun double-every-other (xs)
  (loop for x in xs by #'cddr collect (* x 2)))
```

However, this will double every other element and only return the elements that were doubled, so if I executed:

```
(double-every-other '(1 2 3 4))
```

The result would be:

```
'(4 8)
```

But I want the result to be:

```
'(1 4 3 8)
```

Is there a way I can do this using (loop)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can for instance test an integer increasing while the list is scanned:

```
(defun double-every-other (xs)
  (loop for x in xs
     for i from 1
     if (oddp i)
     collect x
     else collect (* x 2)))
```

Answer (score 11):

Another version with less math:

```
(defun double-every-other (list)
  (loop
     for (a b) on list by #'cddr
     collect a
     when b collect (* b 2)))

(double-every-other '(1 2 3 4))
=> (1 4 3 8)

(double-every-other '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> (1 4 3 8 5)
```

Obviously, you won't be able to abstract the N as easily as the other answer (if you are thinking "macro", stop now). Here we iterate using the `on` keyword, which means each sublist is visited in turn. Since we use `by #'cddr`, every other sublist is skipped. The destructuring syntax `(a b)` binds the first and second elements of the visited list.

Comment: Does not work for a list with an odd number of elements.

Comment: @Renzo Thanks, I missed it

Answer (score 6):

```
(defun double-every-other (xs)
  (loop for x in xs
        for doublep = nil then (not doublep)
        collect (if doublep (* x 2) x)))
```

Answer (score 3):

another version, without loop at all:

```
(defun make-cycled (&rest items)
  (setf (cdr (last items)) items))

(mapcar #'funcall
        (make-cycled #'identity (lambda (x) (* 2 x)))
        '(10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3))

;;=> (10 18 8 14 6 10 4 6)
```

Comment: An interesting hack.  Do I understand correctly that `make-cycled` is creating a self-referential list, that's thus effectively infinite (or rather, it's a sort of circular ("cycled") list), so that the `mapcar`/`funcall` combo can just walk through as much of that as is needed to get through the data?  Interesting indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `loop` "on" list iteration primitive. This takes a list of loop variables that will be "smeared" across the list, with the last being the tail of the entire remaining list. The conditional `loop` for is necessary to avoid multiplying `nil` if we have an odd number of arguments.

```
(defun double-every-other (list)
  (loop for (single double tail) on list by #'cddr
    if (null double)
      collect single
    else
      append (list single (* 2 double))))
```

And if we try to run it:

```
* (double-every-other '(1 2 3 4 5))

(1 4 3 8 5)
```